# Replace and remove characters in string, and add output as new column

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have an output from a program that I would like to process and If I pipe it to a file I get:

```
file/path@backup2018
file2/path/more/path/path@backup2019
file3/path@backup2017
```

And I want to process it so it looks like this:

```
file/path                   file.path
file2/path/more/path/path   file.path.more.path.path
file3/path                  file.path
```

I have figured out how to make it with separate commands but would like a one liner.

Comment: Welcome to SO, we do encourage users to add their efforts in their post, so kindly do add yours which you have put in order to solve your own problem please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F@ '{s=$1; gsub("/", ".", s); print $1, s}' file | column -t
file/path                  file.path
file2/path/more/path/path  file2.path.more.path.path
file3/path                 file3.path
```

Answer (score 0):

using `sed`

```
sed 's/\([^@]*\)@.*/\1 \1/g' file|column -t
```